# In the first column (#0) of a ttk.Treeview, each cell prompts text with a slight downard shift. Why is that?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

This is not a big issue, however it bugs me. It seems that the text within the cells of the first column `#0` of `ttk.Treeview` is shifted downard. The result is not very clean, as part of the text is hided.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x900")

choices = ("Author", "John", "Mohan", "James", "Ankur", "Robert")

master_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
master_frame.pack(expand = True, fill = "both")

tree = ttk.Treeview(master_frame)
tree["columns"]=("Test1", "Test2") 
tree.pack(fill = "both")
for item in choices:
    tree.insert('', 'end',item ,text = item, 
          values = (item, "Hello_W0rld"))
        
message_txt = tk.StringVar()
def what():
    message_txt.set(", ".join(tree.selection()))
ttk.Button(master_frame, text = "Name it!", 
        command =  what).pack()
    
ttk.Label(master_frame, textvariable = message_txt).pack()
    
root.mainloop()
```

[Result of the previous code: the text is partially hided in the first column of the Treeview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLbNv.jpg)

Am I doing something wrong?
If not , are there solutions?
For instance, is there a way to have control over the width of a row? Or simply the anchor of the text whithin a cell?
Thanks in advance, have a nice day.

Comment: you can use ttk.Style(). in `Treeview` config use `rowheight`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
treestyle = ttk.Style()  
treestyle.theme_use("clam")
treestyle.configure("Treeview",
                    rowheight=30)
```

Comment: This works very well! However, I still don't understand why this issue is there at all. It looks like anchor does not work either on column #0 for me..  For instance, `tree.column("#0", anchor = "nw")` should do the trick but it does nothing (whereas it works just fine with the other columns..) Thus I'm a bit confused.

Comment: `tree.column("#0", width=0, stretch="no")` this is one method to skip this. the `#0` is usually using for things like a "listbox`. https://tk-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tree/tree.html